# Is there a way to generate just random "times"?

Tags: r, random, time, sampling

I know that you can use as.POSIXct to generate dates and times. But I want to generate just the times ex) 05:16 (min:sec) 
Does anyone know how to do it? I could not find any package for just time.

Comment: time is basically two numbers `[0-23]` and `[0-59]`, so generate two numbers and you have your time, another approach is to figure out that hours are minutes actually, so generate number in range `[0-1439]` and then use `n/24` to get hours, `n%60` to get minutes

Comment: R doesn't have a built in data type for just times without dates. It only has a date+time class. Not sure what you were hoping to do with these times after you generate them, but if you say a bit more, we might be able to suggest solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick yes I am running a simulation and I want to random sample (n=30)  a time between 0:00 and 9:59 (min:sec). That's all I am trying to do

Comment: So just generate a random variable that's the number of minutes since midnight and have that go from 0 to 599 (9*60+59).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lubridate` is currently the most friendly package to deal with times. Just generate the interval you need and sample from that:

```
library(lubridate)

> sample(as.duration(0:599), 30)
[1] "345s (~5.75 minutes)" "277s (~4.62 minutes)" "74s (~1.23 minutes)" 
[4] "15s"                  "571s (~9.52 minutes)" "186s (~3.1 minutes)" 
[7] "45s"                  "355s (~5.92 minutes)" "121s (~2.02 minutes)"
[10] "488s (~8.13 minutes)" "179s (~2.98 minutes)" "371s (~6.18 minutes)"
[13] "515s (~8.58 minutes)" "31s"                  "346s (~5.77 minutes)"
[16] "0s"                   "398s (~6.63 minutes)" "84s (~1.4 minutes)"  
[19] "160s (~2.67 minutes)" "457s (~7.62 minutes)" "94s (~1.57 minutes)" 
[22] "212s (~3.53 minutes)" "591s (~9.85 minutes)" "576s (~9.6 minutes)" 
[25] "348s (~5.8 minutes)"  "314s (~5.23 minutes)" "563s (~9.38 minutes)"
[28] "509s (~8.48 minutes)" "538s (~8.97 minutes)" "71s (~1.18 minutes)"
```

Check the functions interval() and ms() for other possible ways to get what you want.

But as pointed out in the comments, if what you need is simply random intervals in seconds, it is simpler and more convenient to work with integers.